# RSpec keeps instance variable between post requests

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

In a specific test, I want to add multiples items (`package_sets`) in some orders from my site.

To test it, I do as follow

```
  context "with multiple package sets from different shops" do

    let(:package_sets) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:package_set, 3) }

    it "adds package sets to multiple orders" do
      package_sets.each do |package_set|
        post :create, {'package_set_id': package_set.id}
        expect_json(success: true)
      end
      expect(Order.count).to eq(3)
    end

  end
```

In the real world, each time I call `post :create` it will assign the package set to a different order ; the total number of orders should be 3.

In my controller I memoize the order within a method like this

```
def order
   @order ||= cart_manager.order(shop: package_set.shop, call_api: false)
end
```

Because it's 3 different requests, I was expecting the test to reload this method too without memoization, but it keeps the `@order` memoized between the the `post` requests which makes the test fails.

How do you prevent this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is that RSpec doesn't create new controller instances within your example; you could overcome this by leaking some of that logic into your tests:

```
controller.instance_variable_set(:@order, nil)
```

Perhaps the code was shortened for this particular question, but would you consider testing the controller for a single action?

```
package_set = FactoryGirl.create(:package_set)
expect do
  post :create, {'package_set_id': package_set.id }
end.to change(Order, :count).by(1)
```

Comment: working solution, i'll approve it, but isn't there any other solution to actually reload it manually via RSpec ?

Comment: @Laurent Perhaps your example is very minimal, but why test a controller three times, and then check whether it was done three times? Why not just test it once?

Comment: Yes the tests set was shortened, I'm already testing with one request before. I'm testing it this way because there's a fat order assignment logic beneath all that and I need to make sure it acts correctly when you add successively the items ..

Comment: @Laurent okay, just saying that based on the question alone, there seems to be little merit to testing successive creation

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the `@order` variable in a [before](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before(:each)-block)-block:

```
describe Class do
    before(:each) do
        @order = Order.new()
    end

    context "with multiple package sets from different shops" do
        #...
    end
end
```

Comment: That's not ideal because it moves the controller logic within the test which might makes problems later on, but the idea is here. I wanted to avoid to do that but I see there's not much else to do ...